# Unir 2 imagenes con php

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo que 2 imágenes `png` se combinen o se unan la primera imagen es un codigo QR que lo genero con una libreria y que se autogenera por cada cliente la segunda es una imagen base que es como fondo pero no
lo logro , me aparece al final toda la pantalla negra con un cuadro
blanco pequeño , alguien sabe a que se debe . YA INTENTE VARIAS COSAS
PERO NO ME RESULTA

**Este es el código :**

```
<?php 
 // HACER MI QR
  require 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php'; 
 $dir="boletosQr/";
  if (!file_exists($dir)) 
mkdir($dir);

$filename=$dir."qr.png";
//Paso de variables
$name="Arturo Kasim Simerez";
$evento="Mex-Austin";
$fecha="2018-Agosto-1325552";
$rival_1="Mexicah ";
$rival_2="Austin Wild";
$email="perriro@dominio.com";
$tipoBoleto="Cortesia";//Cortesia o Cortesia Doble
///configurar
$tamanio=8;
$level="Q";
$frameSize=3;
$contenido=$name.''
        .$evento.''
        .$fecha.'';
QRcode::png($contenido,$filename,$level,$tamanio,$frameSize);
echo "<img src='$filename'/>";//Funcionando Bien

 // FUSION DE IMAGENES - AQUI PROBLEMA

 header("Content-type: image/PNG"); 

 // Creamos las dos imágenes a utilizar 
 $imagen1 = imagecreatefrompng('boleto_template.png'); 
/*ImageBase600(W)x330(HEIGHT) $image1 */
 $imagen2 = imagecreatefrompng($filename); //Imagen 344 x 344 px filename 
 esta arriba en el QR

 // Copiamos una de las imágenes sobre la otra 
 imagecopy($imagen1,$imagen2,0,0,0,0,200,150); 

 // Damos salida a la imagen final 
imagejpeg($imagen1); 

 // Destruimos ambas imágenes 
 imagedestroy($imagen2); 
 imagedestroy($imagen1); 

  ?>
```

Por favor ayúdenme Hola, estoy haciendo que 2 imágenes `png` se combinen o se unan pero no lo logro, me aparece al final toda la pantalla negra con un cuadro blanco pequeño, alguien sabe a que se debe.
[image: imagen Base][image: codigoQr]

Comment: saludos revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876299/merging-two-images-with-php

Comment: ¿Puedes decirnos por qué usas esto: `header("Content-type: image/PNG"); `? Ten en cuenta que cuando usas cualquier `header` antes de él no debe salir nada por pantalla, como por ejemplo el `echo` que tienes antes. Además si tus imágenes son archivos y quieres mostrarlas en un HTML no veo necesidad de usar `header` sino `src` como de hecho veo que también intentas hacer. En cuanto a posicionarlas, lo mejor sería usar reglas CSS para eso. De todos modos no queda claramente explicado el contexto en el que te mueves, de dónde vienen las imágenes, etc. Si pudieras aclararlo.

Comment: gracias amigo !!!